# MongoDB : Time comparison

Tags: mongodb

I have a field `startTime` in MongoDB collection that stores time in the following form:

`2015-07-22 08:19:04.652Z`

I would like to find all documents that has the `startTime` greater than or equal to yesterday's time(from exactly one day before). I tried using the $currentDate in the find query, but I was not able to make it work.

EDITED:
Sample Document:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55af5241e4b0ec7c53360333"),
        "startTime" : ISODate("2015-08-22T08:19:04.652Z"),
        "sampleId" : "SS10"
}
```

EDITED 2: No aggregation framework allowed.

Comment: No you cannot use `$currentDate` I think aggregation will work here. Can you edit your post and add sample document?

Comment: I need to do it without aggregation. Is it possible? Assume the document only has this field. I do not understand how a sample document will help.

Comment: do you want exactly one day before or at least one day before?

Comment: I need all documents that have startTime greater than or equal to yesterday's time. I apologize for the mistake in my question. I will update it.

Answer (score 6):

Compute the previous date first the pass it in find query.

In javascript:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
db.col.find({'startTime':{'$gte':date}})
```

Comment: Hi Arun, I am trying to do this without the aggregation framework.

Comment: Oh ... then first compute last day's date first the and pass it to find query with $gt